# Who Fixed The Sonar Issue

Tags: sonarqube

We have a SonarQube 6.0 server with enabled SCM plug-in. So the REST webservice returns the author for each new issue.

While this is an important information, the person who fixed the issue is also important to me. The assignee seems to be that person, however the issues are auto-assigned to whoever created them and their assignee doesn't get changed when somebody else commits a fix. (And yes, the author *should* fix the issues, but often they don't.)

Things I tried:

- Rerun Sonar on a project that was not changed since the SCM plug-in was introduced: the author was filled with the committer, and the assignee was only filled if there is currently a Sonar user with the same name
- introduced a new issue - both the assignee and the committer where set to the committer
- fixed an issue with an assignee: nothing changed
- fixed an issue without an assignee: nothing changed

So from that I assume if I wanted to fix an issue, I had to manually open the Sonar Website, find the project, find the issue, assign it to me, than commit. That's not really acceptable. So I assume there is some other way for Sonar to handle that information.

How do I find out who fixed a Sonar issue?

Comment: Maybe you want to explain the downvotes, so I can improve the question?

Comment: Out of curiosity, _why_ do you want to know who fixed an issue?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I guess similar reasons as for knowing who created an issue: if team members don't fix them (maybe not even their own) there is a problem we need to address (Can they work with the tooling? Do they understand why it's an issue? Maybe their English isn't that good?). And I still believe we can achieve a bit of extra motivation to clean up existing code, but how would we do that if we can't track who fixes issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to do this because:

When an issue is created, it's associated with a line in a file, and assigned to its "creator", the last person to touch that line.

When an issue closed, it stays associated to its file, but loses the line association. So there's no way to attach "praise" to a closed issue because we've lost the link between the issue and the person - the line number.

On a side note, you say something about assigning yourself issues on SonarQube before fixing them. Perhaps that was in an attempt to make the "praise" association, but there's no reason to do this.

To the issue of knowing who's not fixing their issues: you can always search by assignee (and/or creator) in the Issues interface. The Issue count and age you see there should give you some idea of what's going on.